# How do I edit the archive page for the Divi theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a pretty decent wordpress coder.  Maybe I'm being stupid, but I can't work out how to edit the Divi blog module layout... basically the `archive.php` for the Divi theme - it doesn't seem to have one.

What I want to do is change the HTML of the blog when it added to the Divi page builder as a module... How do I go about editing the code for that?

(I've searched everywhere and they all talk about CSS changes, but I want to edit the HTML that is output as well).

Thanks!

EDIT:  To clarify my question, I'm looking for specific help with DIVI.  I have a good understanding of Wordpress, and know the usual hierarchy structure.  My question for Divi is more to do with the blog module that you add to the Page Builder - that's the bit I want to edit the HTML output of.

All google searches (and stackoverflow!) point me to CSS changes only, but I want to edit the HTML output of that page builder (Which I'm guessing is using a shortcode)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a copy of the index.php file from the Divi parent theme
2. Paste the file into your child theme directory
3. Change the name of the file to archive.php
4. Modify the html/php as you need

That should work :)

Comment: Actually, I tried that very thing, and couldn't get it to work. Here's what did work. Don't use the Divi blog module. Create an empty page, named Blog. Then copy index.php from the Divi theme into your child theme. Rename it home.php. Then go to Settings/Rreading in admin, and change the Posts page to Blog. You can then modify home.php and your changes will be reflected there. I'm not sure why archive.php won't work--I really wanted it to, but it would not pick up my changes, no matter what I did.

Comment: @teebark your solution is technically similar to the steps I posted, but using a different approach and it's weird that my solution didn't work, sorry :(. To understand all this issue, just remember that WordPress will always look for index.php (which has a loop, like archive.php) in case there is no specific/special file (archive.php, single.php, etc.) and that the index.php will display a loop of posts by default. The home.php file is an alternative for posts/blog archive, in case you want to leave index.php intact. More about his at <https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page>

Comment: Working for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a page (under pages in Wordpress) that has an "Archive" template. Check it out and edit that template.

[image]

You can check more about page templates (and maybe even creating your own, if you wish) here - https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/an-introduction-to-wordpress-page-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can use Divi Builder for categories pages or custom categories pages.

You simply have to go in Divi > Theme Builder. Then, go into a new model, and select the archive page you need. Finally, you can add custom content within the builder into the header, body or footer. That content will be available in the archive pages you selected.